# Custom People Picker ADFS by Claim Provider

Tags: claims-based-auth, adfs, claim-provider

I have a farm with claim based / ADFS configured.. I have some Web Services running on it and the "EnsureUser(domain\name)" doesn't work, as people picker do.

I read a lot of stuff online, I try to follow up tutorial like this:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/05/25/replacing-the-out-of-box-name-resolution-in-sharepoint-2010-part-1.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/05/25/replacing-the-out-of-box-name-resolution-in-sharepoint-2010-part-2.aspx

And to install solutions like:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251994.aspx

This last throws an exception that I cannot understand ('cause the library is in gac):

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Audience.AudienceManager' from assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.     at WingtipClaimProviders.AudienceClaimProvider.FillClaimsForEntity(Uri context, SPClaim entity, List`1 claims)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimProvider.GetClaimsForEntity(Uri context, SPClaim entity)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimProviderOperations.ClaimsForEntity(Uri context, SPClaimProviderOperationOptions mode, String[] providerNames, SPClaim entity)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSecurityTokenService.AugmentClaimsIdentity(IClaimsIdentity identity, SPClaim identityC...
```

The thing that really I can't understand is WHY every example adds claims to the collection... Isn't possible to modify a claim and return it? I think of claim like InternalName to be "rewrite at runtime" from i#0.|domain\user to domain\user ?

Another thing I cannot figure out is why nobody created a package with a custom people picker... Does anybody has one to share?

Comment: I don't understand how a custom people picker control will help with a web service. Perhaps you could update the question to be a bit more clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of search I found this project:

http://ldapcp.codeplex.com/

To solve the problem programmatically I find out that I must add a prefix to the mails to search...

On Windows Auth look for "domain\user" was ok and also "user@domain.XX" with claim I must look for:

```
i:05.t|saml provider|user@domain.XX
```